# How do I get CSS vw and vh in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, resolution

I am trying to use the CSS vw and vh values in Javascript because I would like to make them adaptive to changing certain JS variables. However, after researching different methods, the values seem to be off by a little bit because it is messing up my display. I've tried using:

```
viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth;
viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

and

```
 viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 viewPortHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

But they do not seem to be working.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine just concatenate the **viewPortWidth** and **viewPortHeight**
with **"px"**, like this,

```
viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth + "px";
viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight + "px";
```

I think this will work just fine, try it.

Comment: Css doesn't understand raw values from javascript so giving it a  unit will help CSS understand. Moreover, the values coming from window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight is in pixels. So you get the basic idea, right ?

Comment: Ah yes, that makes total sense! Thank you so much. I'm still very new to CSS so this helps a lot!

Comment: Css is easy to learn but tough to master, so yeah thank you very much, I was pleased to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// console.log(document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

var getrects=()=>["top","left","height","width",
              "x","y","right","bottom"
             ].map(a=>[a,document.body.getBoundingClientRect()[a]]).concat([['window height',window.innerHeight],["window width",window.innerWidth]]);

//var entries0=getrects();

//entries0.forEach(a=>console.log(a));

const tabler=(
  tbl=document.getElementById("table"),
  entries=getrects())=>(tbl.innerHTML='',
  tbl.innerHTML=`<thead>
<tr>${entries.map(a=>`<th>${a[0]}</th>`).join("")}</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>${entries.map(a=>`<td>${Math.round(a[1])}px</td>`).join("")}</tr></tbody>`
);

window.addEventListener("resize",e=>tabler());
tabler();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:1em;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
html{padding:0; margin:0;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;
  position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top: 0; bottom: 0px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  
}









table {
    margin: 1em;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
/*     border: 1px solid */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #000;
        border: #a2a9b1  ridge 1px;
    font-size: 100%;
    display: table;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
    margin: 1em 0;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
/*     border: 4px solid #a2a9b1; */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #000;
}
caption{font-weight: 600; border: #a2a9b1  ridge 1px;background: white; border-bottom: 0px; padding: .3em;}
tbody{
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
    padding: .2em;
}
tr > th {
    background-color: #eaecf0;
    text-align: center;
}
tr > th, tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}
th.thleft{
     text-align: left;
    padding-right: 1.6em;
}
p{margin:1em;}
```

```html
<h4>The css you likely want is below</h4>
<code>
 
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
html{padding:0; margin:0;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;
  position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top: 0; bottom: 0px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  
}
</code>
<p>  Then just check window.innerWidth and innerHeight as well as the bounding rects on document.body...
  </p>

<p> you can also propertize the body rects nad then just pass them down your node tree.</p>
<table id="table">
  
</table>
```

check out this pen it gets vh and vw both of the body element and the inner window.  Move the side bar around and the domrects in the table will change on resize.

https://codepen.io/jfrazz/pen/KKZeaGe